# my texts keep breaking down into new paragraphs in css and html

Tags: html, css

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="box one">
            <img src="img\xii.jpg" alt="phone1" />
            <section class="section1">
                <p>Xiaomi X15</p>
                <br />

                <h2>New Powerhouse Phone From The Xiaomi Brand</h2>
                <br />
                <button><a href="#"> BUY NOW</a></button>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid black;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.one p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -350px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    left: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-family: calibri;
}
.section1 h2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -500px;
    left: 300px;
    color: white;
}
```

[image]

please help im a beginner in css and this is my first stackoverflow post
my texts are not horizantally in place and keeps breaking down that each word forms a new paragraph how can i solve this please? i have tried the display:inline- block but it didnt work.as you can see from my code i made the div tag that the image is on to be position relative so i can move the h2 and span and button elements to be nn the image. i intend on using flexbox because on i want to position more images to be on the side of the initial image

Comment: you are giving your wrapper 100px width: ` .wrapper{
        width: 100px;
        max-width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto ;
    } ` means it will break at 100px

Comment: use top instead of  `bottom: -350px;` // remove negative value by use `top`.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is:

1. Define some width and height (`max-width` and `min-width` to be more flexible) for your box;
2. Use `background-image` CSS prop instead of HTML `<img />`, which will ensure the image fills the background of your container;
3. Use flex-box with its all properties to lay out your elements. There will be no need for `position: absolute` for the text and header.

Other notes to your code: there are some closing tags missing in your HTML as well as closing `}` braces in the CSS. That is never a good practice to leave your code without them, even though in some cases the browser can fill them out for you.

Here is an example of how you can achieve what you were asking about:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto ;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
} 

.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  background-color:#fff;
  border: 2px solid black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 400px;
    }
.one {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.thewirecutter.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/smartphone-tp-top-2x1-lowres1024-7951.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}   
.section1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.section1 p{
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-family: calibri; 
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0
}
.section1 h2{
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0
}

button {
  max-width: 100px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="box one">
      <section class="section1">
        <p>Xiaomi X15 </p>
        <h2>New Powerhouse Phone From The Xiaomi Brand</h2>
        <button><a href="#"> BUY NOW</a></button>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="box one">
      <section class="section1">
        <p>Xiaomi X15 </p>
        <h2>New Powerhouse Phone From The Xiaomi Brand</h2>
        <button><a href="#"> BUY NOW</a></button>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```